# EditText in listview - gaining focus only after second click

Tags: android, focus, expandablelistview

I am using an ExpandableListview and EditTexts as child items.

Now if I click on the EditText, I see the cursor, which I presume means that the EditText is focused. But then the keyboard appears, and the focus is lost. I have to touch the EditText a second time for it to gain focus.

I tried it with the following in the getChild()-method:

```
holder.title = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);                     
holder.title.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                 v.requestFocus();

                Log.e("touched", "touched");

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Which doesn't work.
I also tried

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

but that didn't seem to have any kind of effect.

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Are you handling the soft keyboard yourself?

Comment: @zgc7009 No, it is appearing when I click into the EditText